# Consumer Batteries Needed to Ignite a 10ohm Resistor

Tags: batteries, resistors

What is the best battery(ies) to ignite a 10ohm 1/4w carbon resistor? Something that I can buy at my local supermarket. I hear the main problem is internal resistance in the batteries. Ideally, I would like to make a package the size of a zippo lighter to ignite them.

Comment: Are you trying to start a fire?

Comment: @MattYoung I'm trying to make a cheap source of model rocket igniters for myself.

Comment: Use a much smaller resistance value and power rating. See my answer as to why.

Comment: You're better off with steel wool, a match, and a 9v battery for a cheap igniter.

Comment: Or a length of nichrome wire.  Which of course, is the same as the ignitor you're trying to avoid buying.

Comment: It would probably be much easier to ignite a tantalum dipped capacitor.

Answer (score 3):

Ohm's law says sqrt(P/R) = I. So your resistor can handle *at least* sqrt(0.25/100) = **50mA** (not much).

In practice, because parts are designed to do exactly the opposite of what you want (e.g. not explode), they can handle much more than that (don't ever design in parts beyond spec in products or anything you ever share with anyone!!!).

10X that (>500mA) should do the trick, but that doesn't necessarily guarantee that it's internal ignition will result in external flame. Many parts are coated to prevented this and the chemistry is always being improved to further reduce the risk of a secondary ignition. That's how products catch fire (a VERY bad thing).

To get 500mA through 100 Ohms you need V = IR = 0.5 * 100 = 50V source. That's about 30 E91 ("AA") batteries in series.

If you reduce your resistor to an 1/8W 1 Ohm part, you can relax your battery requirements much more. Repeating the math...

sqrt(0.125/1)*1 = 350mV, something easily achieved in just a single "AA" battery. At 1 Ohm, the current demand will be 1.5A (approx) from an "AA" battery, so you need a battery with 1C rating > 2A for safety (so that the battery doesn't ignite too!).

I don't think this is necessarily a bad question. Since it's clear that the OP is doing something dangerous that others shouldn't attempt. Sometimes you have to experiment "on the edge" to truly grasp concepts... just sayin'

Comment: 10ohm -> 10 Ohm ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, now I see... ha ha